# Container .NET Core Web App on Linux Docker SQL Server Connection

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kestrel

We have a .NET CORE web application running in Docker container on Linux. Our application connects to SQL Server. We have a requirement to connect to the database using Windows Authentication, and from my IIS experience I know that application needs to run within the context of the AD user that will be used to connect to SQL using Windows Auth.

Am I correct in this assumption? How do I define this with web app running on Kestrel in Linux Docker?

Comment: Maybe this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4198) can help you

Comment: Currently, it is impossible to use AD Authenticaiton in Linux container,  you may consider changing to `SQL Server Authentication` and then use username and password in docker container.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. Currently, researching this article to see if it can help
Authenticate .NET Core Client of SQL Server with Integrated Security from Linux Docker Container:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1272546/Authenticate-NET-Core-Client-of-SQL-Server-with-In

Comment: @Dmitriy, any results?